# my implementation of linked list doesn't print out anything

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have implemented the linked list in the code below but it doesn't print out anything. in the code I have add 3 nodes. someone please tell me where I am wrong. thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
}node;

node* insert_head(node *head, int value){
    node *temp;
    temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->value=value;
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
    }
    else{
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
    return temp;
}

void printlist(node *head){
    node *p=head;
    while (p->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", p->value);
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    node *head;
    head=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->value=0;
    head->next=NULL;
    insert_head(head, 1);
    insert_head(head, 2);
    insert_head(head, 3);
    printlist(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you want: "0 1 2 3" or "3 2 1 0"?

Comment: I mean "3 2 1 0". the name of the function is insert to head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
head=temp;
```

within the function `iinsert_node` does not make a sense because within the function there is changed its local variable head that is a copy of the original argument head. Changing of a copy of a variable does not influence on the stored value of the original variable.

You are not using the return value of the function `insert_head`. You have to write at least like

```
head = insert_head(head, 1);
```

or more safe

```
node *temp = insert_head(head, 1);

if ( temp != NULL ) head = temp;
```

The if statement within the function

```
if (head==NULL)
{
    head=temp;
}
```

is redundant. The function can look like

```
node* insert_head(node *head, int value){
    node *temp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->value = value;
        temp->next = head;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

And the function `printlist` in general has undefined behavior necause head can be equal to NULL. Rewrite it like

```
void printlist(node *head){
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf("%d ", head->value);
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: can you expain to me why function insert_head must return the temp variable then assign to head? I thought the function insert_head had assigned temp to head already?

Comment: I think head is a pointer so it can be changed its value if I pass head's address to the function? I learnt that pass an address of any variables to a function can change its value in global, doesn't it right?

Comment: @Becker You are trying to change the value of the pointer itself not the object pointed to by the pointer (addressed by the stored value)